# Postgresql, hibernate "is not distinct"

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, entitymanager

Is there easy way to write `is not distinct` using `CriteriaBuilder` without `Disjunction`?

**SQL condition**

```
where field1 is not distinct from field2
```

Comment: `a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b` is equivalent to `((a IS NULL AND b IS NULL) OR (a = b))`. So you can formulate it that way.

Comment: @Craig Ringer Thank you. I know, that's why I asked without using `Disjunction`.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Haven't had to use Criteria for 2 years, so I've thankfully been able to purge most of it from my brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as creating own function which will check 2 fields using native `is not distinct`.
Then I could use my function in `CriteriaBuilder` via method [function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...)).